# Using Bearer auth Token to get logged in user Information - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bearer-token, laravel-sanctum

When a user logs in, or registers an account, an auth token is stored on the local storage. Now I want to use this token to get the logged in user information to display on my app for example the username and phone number.

I can get the user information using the token on my Postman. But now how do I display it on the reactjs app?

Here is the Api

```
public function me(Request $request){    
    return $request->user();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example if you want to display the user on the first render of the page:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
const fetchUser = async (url) => {
const response = await fetch(url)
const resData = await response.json()
setUser(resData.user)
   }
fetchUser(YOUR_URL)
},[])
```

And then use the JSX syntax inside the React component to display the user.